# groovy:: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline as follows and this pipe line is failing with following error, I suspect there is something funky going on with Java Hashmaps but I am not sure at all can someone help me with that?

```
    pipeline {
        agent { label 'master' }
        parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '123456789.ngrok.io/app-name:v1', description: '', name: 'docker_image', trim: true)
        password(defaultValue: 'app_db_password', description: '', name: 'app_db_password')
        }
        environment {
            .....
        }
        stages {
        stage('DeployAWS') {
                steps {
                    script{
                        withEnv(["ENV_APP_DB_PASSWORD=${params.app_db_password}"]) {
                            env.artifacts = sh(
                                returnStdout: true, 
                                script: """
                                    set +x
                                    python3 some_script.py --app_db_password='${ENV_APP_DB_PASSWORD}'
                                    set -x
                                    """
                                )
                                def encrypted_key_value_map = readJSON text: env.artifacts
                                ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'dev-server', disableHostKeyChecking: true, "-e \"docker_image=${env.docker_image} fernet_key=${encrypted_key_value_map["fernet_key"]} app_db_password=${encrypted_key_value_map["app_db_password"]}\"", inventory: 'playbooks/dvmt30/dev.inv', playbook: "playbooks/dvmt30/deploy-docker.yml"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

ERROR

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{credentialsId=dev-server, disableHostKeyChecking=true, inventory=playbooks/dvmt30/dev.inv, playbook=playbooks/dvmt30/deploy-docker.yml}, -e "docker_image=123456789.ngrok.io/app-name:v1 fernet_key=$$$$$$$$$ app_db_password=*********"]
```

Comment: I suspect you need to add name to `"-e \"docker_image=${env.docker_image} fernet_key=${encrypted_key_value_map["fernet_key"]} app_db_password=${encrypted_key_value_map["app_db_password"]}\""`

Comment: can you show me how to do it ? I am relatively new to java

Comment: You just add parameter name and `:` before it. I don't know which one you need.